# How to disable quickedit for specific block, but keep contextual links

Tags: 9

I want to disable the quick edit feature for a specific block so that it does not show up in the contextual links anymore.
However, I want to keep the other contextual links for this specific block (e.g. configure block).
I do not want to entirely turn off quick edit, because I still need it on some elements.

Hope someone can help with this one?

Comment: You can simply target the ```.context .trigger``` for that block with css, and ```display: none;```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use module https://www.drupal.org/project/block_content_permissions for that. To cite the project page:

> Add the following permissions to allow access to edit blocks in-place (on-page):
>
> - Use contextual links (Contextual Links module)
> - Access in-place editing (optional, Quick Edit module)

However, it might not be feasible depending on the number of blocks on you site.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I gave that module I try, but I could not find a way to just disable quickedit for a specific block without denying overall edit rights for a specific user role.